# How to get resource id with no raw dir

Tags: java, android

I have some media player program, that get all songs from device and then display them.
When I'm trying play some song with `MediaPlayer` I get error, because I don't have the correct resource id (I have no files in `res/raw` for it).
Question : Can I get the correct resource id not from `res/raw` ?
That's my code for read and save in `Song` object, can I get res id from it, or can I just save audio files from device in `res/raw` ?

```
public class MainMediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView songList;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
int currentPosition = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_media_player);

    songList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfMusic);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri uri1 = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(uri1,null, null, null, null);

     songs = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor == null || cursor1 == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Query failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst() || !cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No media on device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);



        int album_artColumn = cursor1.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        do {
            Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(cursor1.getString(album_artColumn));
            songs.add(new Song(cursor.getString(titleColumn),
                    cursor.getString(artistColumn),
                    cursor.getString(durationColumn),
                    cursor.getString(albumColumn),
                    img,
                    cursor.getLong(id)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    final SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs);
    songList.setAdapter(songAdapter);
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are trying to play the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory to play file from `res/raw` folder. You can play the media file from any path  or url.
In your case, the path for the audio files can be fetched using  -

```
String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
```

`path` will contain the fully qualified path of the media file. You can use this file path to play your audio using MediaPlayer.

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(LauncherActivity.this, Uri.parse(path));
 mp.start();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really useful  information !